# Can a batch run as admin launch another batch as limited user?

Tags: windows-7, mappeddrive, uac

I have a batch that is being run with administrative privileges on a Windows 7 machine. That batch has to run another batch, which should access a mapped network drive. However, network drives are only mapped for the non-administrator part of the logged-in user. Since the second batch doesn't need the administrative rights, I'd like it to run as a limited user, and that will let it access the mapped drives. Is there any way to do that?

To make what I want clear, I'd like to get the following flow:

1. User *eran* logs into *PC*. *eran* is a local administrator.
2. *eran* runs *b1.bat* as administrator.
3. *b1.bat* runs *b2.bat* with *eran*'s limited user credentials (how? that's what I'm asking...)
4. *b2.bat* accesses some mapped drives is now has access to.

[Just in case the reason for the problem is not clear...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624)

Comment: Could you use drive mapping in the b2.bat file? net map z: \\server\share. Then follow up with net use z: /d?

Comment: @Nixphoe - well, that's an interesting suggestion... not exactly what I was hoping for, but if there's no other way, I might go for it. Could you please write it as an answer?

Comment: I updated my answer with that suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the runas command. Check out `runas /?` or [Microsoft runas for more info](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true). Put this in your b1.bat file.

```
runas /noprofile /user:username@domain.local "C:\batch\b2.bat"
```

[Credit here](https://superuser.com/questions/105913/run-as-for-a-bat-file)

---

If that doesn't work you could map the drive in the b2.bat file. Add `net map z: \\server\share`. Then follow up with `net use z: /d`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work :(... I'm using the same user to run both batches, and the admin credentials seem to propagate from the first to the second (I can't use some arbitrary local user, because then I won't have the network drives mapped).

Answer (score 1):

Create a scheduled task as user2.
User1 executes that scheduled task which is configured to run in the context of user2.
schtasks is the interface to run from the command line.

"schtasks /Run /TN taskname" would run the batch file for the other user.